# root GNOME terminal many commands not found but all work in root SSH

Tags: bash, shell

root GNOME terminal many commands not found    but all work in root SSH

if i connect remotely or from console they work
example:
GNOME terminal

```
[root@server ~]# which openvpn
/usr/bin/which: no openvpn in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin)
```

SSH terminal:

```
[root@server ~]# which openvpn
/usr/sbin/openvpn
```

THANK You i apologize for an elementary question but i spent a lot of time reading solutions and tried.

Comment: How do you elevate yourself to `root` in Gnome terminal? Your path variable does not contain the `sbin`-type entries in the terminal-case. Compare `echo $PATH` in both cases and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, when you launch a GNOME terminal -- and please, *please* tell me you're not running your entire desktop session as root, I don't need another ulcer right now -- it loads an environment with the `PATH` variable set only to the user-space paths -- `/usr/bin/`, `/bin/`, etc.

OpenVPN is located in `/usr/sbin` because it requires some elevated privileges to be of any use.